# Mysql same querys one with index second without getting 10000xFetch time?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am having problem with performance of db web app. I try to add index to table "to get some time". And its kinda working. Using index I get time diffrence from 20 sec to 3sec what's ok, but the problem is that the time of duration decrease that's ok but fetch is increasing from 0,001 to  about 16 sec?! 
Did any one come acrross such a problem ?

Time for the queries with the same search data:

```
Duration / Fetch             Duration / Fetch   
Orignal query               Query with index    
17.375 sec / 0.016 sec  5.047 sec / 15.140 sec  27197 row(s) returned
17.141 sec / 0.031 sec  2.047 sec / 15.844 sec  32497 row(s) returned
15.984 sec / 0.015 sec  2.938 sec / 16.562 sec  19532 row(s) returned
15.515 sec / 0.000 sec  18.406 sec / 0.000 sec  91 row(s) returned
15.906 sec / 0.015 sec  5.891 sec / 15.390 sec  10278 row(s) returned



SELECT u.id AS ID
from urzadzenie u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN przedmiot pr ON u.id = pr.id_urzadzenie AND pr.del = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN ozf_przedmiot ozf  ON ozf.id_przedmiot = pr.id AND ozf.del = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN zamowienie zm ON zm.id = ozf.id_zamowienie AND zm.del = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN instalacja_urzadzenia i ON u.id = i.id_urzadzenie AND data_usuniecia IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN lokalizacja_urzadzenia lu ON lu.id = i.id_lokalizacja
LEFT OUTER JOIN obiekt o ON i.id_obiekt = o.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN podmiot p ON o.id_podmiot = p.id,wersja_urzadzenia w, typ_urzadzenia t,kategoria_urzadzenia k
LEFT OUTER JOIN urzadzenie_uwagi uuw ON uuw.id = (select max(id) from urzadzenie_uwagi uw WHERE uw.del = 0 AND uw.id_urzadzenie = u.id AND uw.id_urzadzenie_uwagi_rodzaj in (1,2,3,11,12,13))
WHERE ((UPPER(k.nazwa) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%') OR UPPER(t.nazwa) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%')
    OR UPPER(concat(t.nazwa, '-', w.nazwa)) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%') OR UPPER(u.nr_ewidencyjny) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%')
    OR UPPER(u.nr_ewidencyjny2) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%') OR UPPER(p.nazwa) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%')
    OR UPPER(lu.opis) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%') OR UPPER(u.data_produkcji) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%')) )
    AND(u.del = 0 AND u.id_wersja = w.id AND w.id_typ = t.id AND t.id_kategoria = k.id)
ORDER BY ID DESC;


SELECT u.id AS ID
from urzadzenie u use index(part_of_name5)
LEFT OUTER JOIN przedmiot pr ON u.id = pr.id_urzadzenie AND pr.del = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN ozf_przedmiot ozf use index(part_of_name1) ON ozf.id_przedmiot = pr.id AND ozf.del = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN zamowienie zm ON zm.id = ozf.id_zamowienie AND zm.del = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN instalacja_urzadzenia i ON u.id = i.id_urzadzenie AND data_usuniecia IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN lokalizacja_urzadzenia lu ON lu.id = i.id_lokalizacja
LEFT OUTER JOIN obiekt o ON i.id_obiekt = o.id LEFT OUTER JOIN podmiot p ON o.id_podmiot = p.id,wersja_urzadzenia w, typ_urzadzenia t,kategoria_urzadzenia k
LEFT OUTER JOIN urzadzenie_uwagi uuw ON uuw.id = (select max(id) from urzadzenie_uwagi uw WHERE uw.del = 0 AND uw.id_urzadzenie = u.id AND uw.id_urzadzenie_uwagi_rodzaj in (1,2,3,11,12,13))
WHERE ((UPPER(k.nazwa) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%') OR UPPER(t.nazwa) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%')
    OR UPPER(concat(t.nazwa, '-', w.nazwa)) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%') OR UPPER(u.nr_ewidencyjny) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%')
    OR UPPER(u.nr_ewidencyjny2) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%') OR UPPER(p.nazwa) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%')
    OR UPPER(lu.opis) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%') OR UPPER(u.data_produkcji) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%')) )
    AND(u.del = 0 AND u.id_wersja = w.id AND w.id_typ = t.id AND t.id_kategoria = k.id)
 ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL? The result for "duration" and "fetch" look consistent with SQL Server `FIRST 1`/`FASTFIRSTROWS` or Oracle `FIRST_ROWS` behavior, if "duration" is the amount of time until the first row is returned, and "fetch" is the remainder. If MySQL has to perform a sort operation to satisfy the ORDER BY, we'd expect the "duration" to be longer, because MySQL has to have the whole set to know which row should be returned "first". If the ORDER BY can be satisfied by an index instead of sort, then (theoretically) MySQL could return the "first" row before it has accessed all the rows.

Comment: I suspect that for the second query, MySQL is satisfying the ORDER BY with an index, rather than a "Using filesort" operation. We could confirm that suspicion by examining the output from `EXPLAIN`. I also suspect that with the second query, MySQL is starting to return rows as it finds them, it knows they are "in order" already. I suspect that the query hasn't finished, it's still accessing rows after it returns the first row. For the first query, MySQL optimizer is determining that accessing all of the rows, and then doing the sort, and then returning rows will be faster overall.

Answer (score 0):

```
OR UPPER(lu.opis) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%')
```

has 3 performance problems:

- `OR` is poorly optimized.  Essentially, the table must be scanned to check all rows.  Indexes are unlikely to help.
- `UPPER(indexed-column)` prevents using an index on that column.  This is easily worked around declaring that column to have a `COLLATION` that is "case insensitive" -- that is, something like `utf8_unicode_ci`; note the `_ci`.
- `LIKE '%...` cannot use an index because of the *leading* wildcard.

In addition, it is usually foolish to have

```
32497 row(s) returned
```

What are you going to do with that many rows?  The network transfer time will be significant, even if the query itself is not.

To "solve" the `LIKE`, `OR`, and `UPPER` problems all at once, collect the text together into a single column in a single table.  Then provide a `FULLTEXT` index on that column.  The, `MATCH ... AGAINST ...` will run a lot faster -- at least for doing the `SomeName` search.  (The `LEFT JOINs` are another matter.)

Comment: More the question is why the fetch time is increasing(query time decrease), but selected data count did not increase.

Comment: Please explain how you are measuring "fetch" versus "query" times.

Comment: I get thouse times from mysql workbench and from some other sql tool.

Comment: Possibly [_this_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42941933/1766831) explains the "duration" vs "fetch".