# Indexes Show No Improvement In Speed

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a table with about 22 million rows and about 20 columns containing property data. Currently a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM fulldataset WHERE county = 'MIDDLESBROUGH'
```

takes an average of 42 seconds to run. To try and improve this, I created an index on the county column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE fulldataset ADD INDEX county (county)
```

There has been no improvement at all in the speed of the same query.

So I used EXPLAIN SELECT to try and find out what was happening. If I SELECT * from countyA, it returns around 85k entries, after ~42 seconds. If I EXPLAIN SELECT the same query it says it's using the county Index I created and that the number of rows is around 167k, which is wrong but better than searching all 22 million.

Likewise, if I SELECT * for countyB I get around 48k results and EXPLAIN SELECT tells me there are around 91k rows. The EXPLAIN SELECT statement returns the result instantly, so it's able to instantly tell that there are around half as many entries for countyB as there are for countyA. The problem is the queries don't execute any faster. If it's only checking 91k rows shouldn't it be very quick?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm doing: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mX8C.png)

EDIT: As pointed out, the query itself is not what is taking time. In answer to my own question in the comments, a multiple column index worked wonders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is not the problem. If you look closely at the output of your program you will see that the query execution took less than 1s, but fetching all the rows took 42s.

If you have to wait 42s before you see anything then I recommend to use another querying tool which only fetches the first X rows and displays them in pages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Displaying the results isn't really that important so as long as the query time is low that's good. However, when I'm trying to get say, the average price of all entries in a county, do I need to create a multiple column index? Is the index on county not enough? Currently an average price query takes 43 seconds, all duration, not fetch. EXPLAIN SELECT still says it uses the county index for the average price query and that the number of rows is around 91k.

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN` is designed to be fast.  In doing so, the calculation of "Rows" is only a crude estimate.  If can often be off by a factor of 2.  So, don't read too much into 85K vs 167K.

Since `EXPLAIN` is delivering only a single row (or a small number of rows), the "fetch" time is very low.

If you are selecting the `AVG()` of some column, it has to *first* read all the relevant rows, doing the computation as it goes.  It cannot even start to deliver data until it has *finished* all the reading.

If you are reading all the rows, it can (but I am not sure that it does) start delivering rows starting with the *first* row.

If you do something like `SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY x` (and `x` is not indexed), then you get the worst or both worlds.  *First* it has to read all the rows and write them to a temp table, *then* it sorts that temp table; only then can it *begin* to fetch the rows.

I *think* "duration" and "fetch" are not very useful; the sum of the two is more useful.  Here's another example of it:  [Mysql same querys one with index second without getting 10000xFetch time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675897/mysql-same-querys-one-with-index-second-without-getting-10000xfetch-time)
Notice how the sum is consistent, but the separation is not.